# Why the increment operation is executed after multiplication?

Tags: c

Why in this expression increment is evaluated after multiplication? 
It has higher precedence.

y = x * z++;

EDIT:
Another example

```
int i[] = {3, 5};
int *p = i;
int j = --*p++;
```

is equivalent to

```
int j = postincrement(--*p);
```

Comment: Because that is the way opstfis `operator++` works. It is unrelated to precedence.

Comment: independance of precedence - that's huge difference between postfix and prefix increments. I wonder why it is rarely mentioned.

Comment: @UnhandledException Bill Lynch provided an excellent answer. It is useful  to think about the postfix operator as a standalone function, so `x*z++` is translated as `x*postincrement(z)`. This makes it more clear.

Comment: Indeed, now I got it ,when I have some experiments with another piece of code (look at my question's edit)

Comment: @UnhandledException The code in the last edit should be avoided IMO. It just makes the reader [spend some time](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence) figuring out what's the precedence etc.  Just put some parenthesis to improve the readability.

Comment: Not sure where you think precedence comes into this.

Comment: I wonder why this f*cking tutorials  provide examples where only left-assoc. operation participate. What happens when left-assoc operation works with right-assoc operation? I have 7 years experience with C and I have never seen an answer to this question..

Comment: In particular, in this article, there is no single word about associativity! What a shame!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`z++` is more or less the same as:

```
int postincrement(int *z) {
    int temp = *z;
    *z++;
    return temp;
}
```

So your code is more or less equivalent to:

```
y = x * z;
z = z + 1;
```

Comment: nice idea of representing postfix is some kind of function, it's nice to see how it's implemented in C compiler.

Answer (score 1):

It is a postfix operator. The result is first evaluated, then `z` is incremented. So basically the expression looks like:

```
y = x * postincrement(z); // where postincrement was defined in Bill's answer
```

where `postincrement` returns the "old" value of `z` as a temporary, then `z` is incremented, but the incremented `z` does not enter into the expression.

Comment: what does mean result is first evaluated?  Did you mean that z is returned the value to assignment expression or is return to whatever at the left side? and then have to be postfixed?

Answer (score 0):

`++` increment operator. `++` adds 1 to its operand.

If you use `++` before  a variable `++x` it is called `pre-increment` operator.
`++x` increments x and evaluates to the new value of x.

If you use `++` after a variable `x++` it is called `post-increment` operator.
`x++` evaluates to the old value of x, and increments x.

```
y = x * z++;
```

is same as

```
y = x * z;
z = z + 1;
```

Edit:

> Why the increment operation is executed after multiplication?

No. The value of z incremented before multiplication but it evaluates to its old value in the expression due to post increment operator. 
As you said ++ has highest precedence than * so ++ operation completes first not multiplication but the value of z++ evaluates to its old value not the incremented value.

Comment: OP knows. You didn't answer the question at all.

Comment: @Lightness Races in Orbit thanks for pointing that the answer was incomplete. Modified answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

More detail

"Why the increment operation is executed after multiplication?" is a false premise.

The 2nd value given to the multiplication is the "return value" result of `z++`.  The "return value" of `z++` is the *original* value of `z`.  `z++` causes `z` to be incremented.  If this increment happens before or after the multiplication is irrelevant as the product is `x` and the original value of `z`.

Pseudo code: both are possible.

```
 copy z to reg
 inc z
 mult x*reg -> y
```

or

```
 mult x*z -> y
 inc z
```

Comment: Chux, amazing! you have provided details to juanchopanza's comment on origianal question, so int y = z++ * x; gives the same result. We may say: Increment operator is divided into two part: return of value and actual increment.